# Date problems in Firefox & IE

Tags: javascript, date

I am still fairly new with Javascript but I having a problem with dates. My code below works great in Chrome, Safari, and Opera but in Firefox & IE, shows "invalid date." I'm not sure why they aren't working when it works in the other browsers. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
// Perl variable brings in the enrollment date
var enrollDate = new Date(user.joinDate); 
var currentDate = new Date();
var expirationDate = new Date(enrollDate);
expirationDate.setDate(enrollDate.getDate()+7);

$('.hide-mailingAddress').addClass('hidden');
  if (currentDate <= expirationDate) {
  $('.show-mailingAddress').removeClass('hidden');
              }

console.log("Join Date: " + enrollDate);
console.log("Current Date: " + currentDate);
console.log("Expiration Date: " + expirationDate);
```

Here is what Chrome, Safari, Opera outputs:

```
Join Date: Mon Dec 08 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)
Current Date: Mon Feb 02 2015 09:54:27 GMT-0700 (MST)
Expiration Date: Mon Dec 15 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)
```

Firefox & IE Outputs:

```
Join Date: Invalid Date
Current Date: Mon Feb 02 2015 09:49:41 GMT-0700 (MST)
Expiration Date: Invalid Date
```

Comment: What's the value of user.joinDate?

Comment: an example would be Mon Dec 08 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)

Comment: `new Date('Mon Dec 08 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)')` works just fine in Firefox, show us a case that doesn't work.

Comment: its not always that date. the date is pulled in via a Perl variable.

Comment: And the date is always in that format?

Comment: yes. that is correct. but for some reason Firefox and IE say "invalid date" for the enrollDate & expirationDate

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In some versions of IE `new date()` doesn't return as expected.
You may want to use:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var finalDate   = currentDate.getFullYear() + "/" + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + currentDate.getDate();
```

Btw, `currentDate.getMonth() + 1` is because it starts on **0**

Comment: the currentDate works fine in all the browsers. Its the enrollDate & expirationDate that shows "invalid date"

Comment: Can you output the variable `user.joindate`? Because I've tried with IE 9 and Firefox 34.0.5 and it works. http://jsfiddle.net/0cjzrczo/

Comment: Please see comment above with Andrew C. It is pulled in with a Perl variable. Its not the same date all time. It puts it in a format of "Mon Dec 08 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)"

Comment: You know that the problem is because of the Perl variable, you'll have to  check for the value of it and give us the value that is causing you error. Use `console.log(user.joinDate)`.

Comment: I've checked with the programmer and the variable is fine

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that user.joinDate is a quoted string:

Such as: ' "Mon Dec 08 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)" '

This extra set of quotes fails in Internet Explorer but is parsed fine by Chrome.

```
new Date('"Mon Dec 08 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)"')
```